# What exactly is VBScript, and what books/online resources could I use to learn it?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I have some programming knowledge, I can write console applications in Python, Java, and I can do both console and GUI programs with VB.net. Since I know VB.net, I though I should learn VBScript. I read online that it is a language used on Internet Explorer, but the tech department at my school writes applications in a text editor and saves them as a .vbs and runs them on the computer(no browser needed). I have used this method to make a simple Message Box(MsgBox"message here",4,"title here"). Is this a single language able to be used in both environments, or are these two separate things?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I read online that it is a language used on Internet Explorer...***

Yes, VBScript can be used as an alternative to JavaScript. But, in practice, nobody uses VBScript for web application development because it works *only* in Internet Explorer.

***...but the tech department at my school writes applications in a text editor and saves them as a .vbs and runs them on the computer(no browser needed).***

Yes, and many problems can be solved with VBScript. VBScript is a complete programming language and it can access the COM subsystem in Windows. What I like about VBScript is that it is available on ***all*** Windows systems. So, it is wonderful solution when you have restrictions that prohibit you from installing other language interpreters/runtimes such as the Java JRE, Python, Perl, Ruby, etc.

For an example of what you can do with VBScript, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371712/1497596) which demonstrates reading a key from the Windows Registry.

And check out my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371416/1497596) for a pointer to downloading Microsoft's authoritative VBScript reference as a Windows help file.

All that said, Microsoft has pretty much stopped enhancing VBScript and is putting its energy into **PowerShell**. PowerShell is very much aimed at System Adminstrators and it is an exceptionally capable language when used for that purpose. However, the last time I looked, PowerShell was weak with respect to creating your own classes. (Or at least it was awkward.) As an application developer, though, when I am solving a problem with VBScript, I typically make use of classes via the `Class` keyword extensively. A lot of folks don't know this, but you can do object-oriented programming in VBScript, and I do so often.

Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065343/1497596) that shows how you can develop your own classes via the `Class` keyword in VBScript.